# Symfony2 - Updating an entity in a one-to-one relationship

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, orm

I am trying to update my SingleTask entity however no change is accepted. The relationship between my Event and SingleTask is a bi-directional one-to-one relationship.

The relevant portions of my Event entity are:

```
class Event
{
   // properties

   /**
    * @OneToOne(targetEntity="SingleTask", mappedBy="event", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    */
   private $singletask;

   public function setSingleTask(SingleTask $singletask)
   {
      $this->singletask = $singletask;
      $singletask->setEvent($this);
   }

   public function getSingleTask()
   {
      return $this->singletask;
   }
}
```

The relevant portions of my SingleTask entity are:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class SingleTask
{
   /**
    * @Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
    */
   private $lastRun;

   /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="singletask")
     * @JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     **/
   private $event;

   public function setLastRun(\DateTime $lastRun = null)
   {
      $this->lastrun = $lastRun;
   }
}
```

In a separate command file:

```
$eventRepo = $this->em->getRepository('HeyRemy\HeyRemyBundle\Entity\Event');
$events = $eventRepo->findAll();

foreach ($events as $event)
{
   $singletask = $event->getSingleTask();

   if ($singletask != null)
   {
      $singletask->setLastRun(new \DateTime);
      $event->setSingleTask($singletask);

      $this->em->flush();
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, the lastRun property on the SingleTask is never updated in the database. What is not correct?

Edit: Code samples of how I create an event:

```
$event = new Event();
$userRepo = $this->em->getRepository('HeyRemyBundle:User');
$user = $userRepo->find($user_id);
$event->setUser($user);

$this->em->persist($event);
$this->em->flush();

$event_id = $event->getId();

// other code which uses $event_id (SingleTask does not)

$singletask = new SingleTask();
$singletask->setNextRun($event_start);

$this->em->persist($singletask);

$event->setSingleTask($singletask);

$this->em->flush();
```

Comment: If you already have the singletask object, why are you fetching it again?

Comment: @JasonRoman Good observation. I have removed the redundant fetching of the SingleTask object and updated the code in my question above. Still no change in results (which is the SingleTask database row not changing).

Comment: Can you post more code in regards to how you create the event?  If the event already exists, you do not need to call `persist` again, just `flush`.  Also, you do not need to say `->setSingleTask` since you already grabbed it from the `$event`.

Comment: @JasonRoman I have updated the command file code to show how I retrieve all existing event objects from the Event repository. I also removed the persist() call and the result is the same. From my understanding, retrieving the SingleTask from the Event object, updating its information and setting it back to the Event object and then flushing the Entity Manager should be enough...

Comment: One comment - you can skip `$event->setSingleTask($singletask);` in your loop because that's already connected to the event, and you can move your `$this->em->flush();` outside of the `foreach()` - it'll handle all of the updates at the end rather than through each loop iteration.  But I have to ask the obvious.  Look in your database...are you *sure* that these events have a single task entity associated with them?  It looks like you aren't setting an event on your single tasks - check those in the database and see if `event_id` is null (and I wouldn't allow `nullable` here either).

Comment: In my database, the singletask table does have the correct event_ids for the foreign keys; no event_id is null. I removed the `$event->setSingleTask($singletask);` method call and moved `$this->em->flush();` outside the foreach loop. The results haven't changed. I'm not sure why it isn't updating.

Comment: Can you remove the `if ($singletask != null)` or put an echo or something inside the loop just to make sure that code is even being reached?

Comment: I have an echo inside and it is correctly iterating over the events. I confirmed that the event ids match the foreign keys in the `singletasks` table. I cleared my cache just to see if that would help as well but it didn't.

Comment: I have a feeling this has to do with the fact that nothing is changing on the event side which is what is being managed. Is there a reason why you are doing the `findAll()` and trying to update every single record in the table?  What is the concept that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Right now I just want to update the `lastRun` field for all events to see if I can. I would add some code later to make sure that only under the condition that the `nextRun` time has passed would I update the events. But right now I'm just testing the ability to update the SingleTask.

Comment: I notice your capitalization is wrong when setting lastrun, which is probably just setting a public variable on the entity rather than the one attached to your database field. PHP variable names *are* case-sensitive.  Make sure it is `$this->lastRun = $lastRun;` with the R capitalized

Comment: @JasonRoman I ... cannot believe I did that. Thanks so much Jason! If you answer it, I can accept it!

Comment: Done - funny how it can be something so minor...but this was a good test of a process to debug and learn about Doctrine along the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments - it turns out this was a simple typo of the `$lastRun` variable.  The variable mapped to the database is `$lastRun`, but your setting is doing `$this->lastrun;`

Since variable names are case-sensitive in PHP, you were simply creating a new public class variable, but that wasn't being mapped to the database.  If you were using PHP's strict mode for errors it would have caught this and thrown an error.

Here's the updated code:

public function setLastRun(\DateTime $lastRun = null)
   {
      $this->lastRun = $lastRun;
   }

Answer (score 0):

Surely I will answer something absurd, but I think the only thing missing in your code is :

```
$this->em->persist($event);
$this->em->flush();
```

I hope this will solve your problem !

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it.

Comment: Do you have some output ?